# ServiceStack - Error trying to resolve Service {X} or one of its autowired dependencies

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am using servicestack and having problems with auto wiring.

> Error trying to resolve Service '{Service}' or one of its autowired dependencies (see inner exception for details)

I don't need help figuring how exactly what the problem is. What I actually want is a way to see the inner exception. The inner exception should tell me the except problem without me having to figure it out but it not displayed in either the exception returned, or in the logs.

Setting DebugMode doesn't help either, it just includes the stack track of the topmost exception.

So basically, how do I stop servicestack from hiding the inner exception details?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue and it ended up being that there was an exception being thrown inside of the constructor that I had created for the particular endpoint class. Example...

```
public class PartnerService : Service
{

    private PartnerManagementService _partnerManagementService;

    public PartnerService()
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        _partnerManagementService = new PartnerManagementService(configuration);
    }

    public object Get(PartnerGet partner)
    {

        try
        {
            var partners = _partnerManagementService.getPartners();

            if (!partners.Any())
            {
                return new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Partners Could not be found");
            }

            return partners;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

If it so happens that an exception is thrown inside of the constructor, ServiceStack will not be able to resolve the service or one of its dependencies, in this case that dependency being the constructor for the class.

If you put a try/catch in the constructor for the class you could get an exception that actually makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

ServiceStack should already return the inner Exception, i.e. here's the [source of the error](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack/Funq/Container.cs#L154):

```
private Exception CreateResolveException<TService>(Exception ex)
{
    var errMsg = "Error trying to resolve Service '{0}' or one of its autowired dependencies (see inner exception for details).".Fmt(typeof(TService).FullName);
    return new Exception(errMsg, ex);
}
```

Basically there was a problem with your IOC configuration and that one of the dependencies caused an error.

You can change ServiceStack to serialize the Inner Exception with:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    ReturnsInnerException = true,
});
```

But this already defaults to true.

So the exception should already contain the Inner Exception, are you referring to what Exception gets serialized or the exception thrown in code?

Comment: Here is the full exception which gets returned http://pastebin.com/j9DFZ9vy. As you can see it doesn't have the inner exception which details what it couldn't map. I am using the default IoC container and it is called in the Configure function of the AppHost. I am using the inbuilt Funq IoC. I have set up the container to use ReuseScope.Request.

Comment: This is strange. I got an IoC error for the IUserAuthRepository (for the CredentialsAuthProvider) and I got the inner exception printed in the logs. This seems to be because this exception is logged from my custom ServiceRunner whereas the other exception (which I don't see the inner exception for) is logged from the EndpointHandlerBase class.

Comment: Unfortunately just setting the ReturnsInnerException = true, will not return an inner exception for this particular error. The only way to actually get the exception is to put the code that is causing an error into a try-catch.

On a side note, the pastebin link doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to grab the actual source code from [Github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src) and add it as a project to your solution, as opposed to using a compiled DLL, then you could step through the actual code and see exactly where the exception is raised and why.

Comment: Err yeah. I'm hoping there is another way. I have actually already solved specific problem but this can happen any time I forget to wire something.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same exception.

In my case, it happens once migrated to ServiceStack v4. With v3, all works perfectly.

### IoC configuration

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Northwind web services", typeof(CustomersService).Assembly)
    { }        


    public override void Configure( Container container )
    {
        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            DebugMode = true,
            ReturnsInnerException = true,
        });         

        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("~/Northwind.sqlite".MapHostAbsolutePath(), SqliteDialect.Provider);

        container.Register(dbFactory);

        // Dependencies
        container.RegisterAs<CustomerEntityRepository, ICustomerEntityRepository>();

        container.RegisterAutoWired<CustomersService>();

    }
}
```

### Base class

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity, new()
{        

    protected IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory { get; set; }

    public Repository( IDbConnectionFactory factory )
    {
        dbFactory = factory;
    }
}
```

### Inherited class

```
public class CustomerEntityRepository : Repository<CustomerEntity>, ICustomerEntityRepository
    {
        public CustomerEntityRepository( IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory )
            : base(dbFactory)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Only solution I've found is:

```
container.RegisterAs<ICustomerEntityRepository>(c => new CustomerEntityRepository(dbFactury));
```

Here's full exception message returned http://pastebin.com/jJntNN5p